# Array of PtrStepSz(GpuMat) to a C CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to modify a GpuMat with the info of an array of GpuMats inside a CUDA kernel.
To modify it I'm sending the GpuMat and converting it to a PtrStepSz in the kernel like:

```
__global__ void func(cuda::PtrStepSz<float> X)
{//...
}
int main()
{//...
    GpuMat X;
    func<<<blocks, threads>>>(X);
}
```

which works ok... Now I'm trying to use the info of an array of PtrStepSz... I've been trying something like:

```
__global__ void func2(cuda::PtrStepSz<float> arr[])
{//...
}
int main()
{
    cuda::PtrStepSz<float> *d_arr;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_arr, sizeof(cuda::PtrStepSz<float>)*N );
    cuda::GpuMat mats[N];
    Mat O = Mat::ones(size, size, CV_32FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      mats[i].upload(O);
      d_arr[i] = mats[i];
    }
    func2<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_arr);
    //...
}
```

which doesn't work... Not even the initialization part (I guess it's because I can't modify GPU contents from CPU)... Any ideas on how to acomplish what I need? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps someone else...
I've managed to solve it by making a CPU array of PtrStepSz, initializing it with GpuMats, then creating a pointer to PtrStepSz to which I allocate and copy the contents of the array on the GPU.
It ended up like this:

```
__global__ void func2(cuda::PtrStepSz<float> arr[])
{//...
}
int main()
{
    cuda::PtrStepSz<float> *sender;
    cuda::PtrStepSz<float> d_arr[N];
    cuda::GpuMat mats[N];
    Mat O = Mat::ones(size, size, CV_32FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      mats[i].upload(O);
      d_arr[i] = mats[i];
    }
    cudaMalloc((void**)&sender, sizeof(cuda::PtrStepSz<float>)*N );
    cudaMemcpy(sender, d_arr, sizeof(cuda::PtrStepSz<float>) * N,
      cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    func2<<<blocks, threads>>>(sender);
    //...
}
```

Anyway I'd be glad to see if anyone has a better idea :)

Comment: thank you so much for the psuedo code. I have a similar issue. Can you direct me to any of your code examples on github so that I can refer to it ?